# mysql query, selecting from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, unique

I am wrangling with a query pulling unique values from 3 tables. Is this better done in 2 separate queries?

the query is to:

```
count as returned (
all leadID from lds where status = "ok"
AND leadID is also in rlds with recID="999"
AND rdate > (03-20-2012)
 + 
(all distinct leadID from plds where recID="999"
AND change != NULL
AND pdate > (03-20-2012))
```

the result of the working query should be "2": leadID 1 and leadID 4

table lds:

leadID | status 
1      | ok
2      | bad
3      | ok

table plds:
leadID | recID | change | pdate 
4      | 999   | ch1    | 03-27-2012
4      | 999   | ch2    | 03-27-2012
5      | 888   | NULL   | 03-27-2012

table rlds:
leadID | recID2 | rdate
1      | 999    | 03-27-2012
6      | 999    | 03-27-2012

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Ids.leadId
FROM
    Ids JOIN
    rlds ON rlds.leadId = Ids.LeadId AND recID = 999 AND rdate > '03-20-2012'
WHERE Ids.Status = 'ok'

UNION

SELECT leadId
FROM pIds
WHERE recID = 999 AND change IS NOT NULL AND pdate > '03-20-2012'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNION key word to retreive a array a 2 row, the first one containing the count of your first match and the seconde the count of your second match.

You can then use the SUM keyword to sum the two row altogether in an enclosing select. The result will be a single row contening your count.

```
SELECT sum(1)
FROM
(
SELECT count(1)
FROM lds
INNER JOIN rlds ON lds.leadid = plds.leadid
WHERE lds.status='ok' AND rlds.recid2=999 AND rlds.pdate > '03-20-2012'

UNION

SELECT count(1)
FROM plds
WHERE plds.recid=999
AND change != NULL
AND pdate > '03-20-2012'
) AS tmpcount
```